# Python: Holding a reference to a subclass of threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a subclass of threading.Thread.  After instantiating it, it runs forever in the background.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            <do something>
```

If I were to instantiate the thread from within another class, I would normally do so with

```
    self.my_thread = MyThread()
```

In cases when I never thereafter have to access the thread, I have long wondered whether I can instead instantiate it simply with

```
    MyThread()
```

(i.e., instantiate it without holding a reference).  Will the thread eventually be garbage collected because there is no reference holding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesnt matter ... you can test it easily with `del self.my_thread` and you should see the thread continue running even though you deleted the only reference and forced garbage collection ... that said it is usually a good idea to hold a reference (so that you can set flags and what not for the other thread, although shared memory may be sufficient)

Comment: It does seem to be true that the thread will continue to run after deleting that reference, but I don't understand why the instance is not deallocated if that reference truly were the last.  Even running gc.collect() does not stop the thread.  As I understand reference counting, objects are deallocated when their reference count reaches 0.  It seems to me that something must still be referencing the instance.  I am wondering what it is and whether I can count on it to persist.

Comment: threads persist ... until they exit ... afaik even if you close the program that spawned the thread the thread will continue  (maybe im confusing with multiprocessing) ...  __the answer is yes you can count on the thread persisting__ , however as I mentioned it is very likely that keeping a reference around is a good idea that will save you pain later ...